# filter deep nested property returns empty array

Tags: javascript, lodash, ecmascript-harmony

I have array of objects

```
var data = [{type:"A",parentPersonInfo:{id:1,fullname:'john smith'}},{type:"A",parentPersonInfo:   {id:1,fullname:'jim smith'}},{type:"B",parentPersonInfo:   {id:2,fullname:'jane smith'}}]
```

I want to use lodash to extract the records where type = A and id = 1

```
const testId = 1;
_.filter(data,{'type':'A','data.parentPersonInfo.id':1});
```

but i get []

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't create a MCVE?

Comment: @Amit what is a MCVE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check if using the code below works?

```
_.filter(data, {type: 'A', parentPersonInfo: {id:1}});
```